# Is keeping the key pressed equal to pressing the key many times quickly

Tags: operating-system, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress, systemevent

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. It's not an application specific question nor it is about any concrete problem. However, to make it more application specific, I'll take the example of Photoshop.

The shortcut to reduce the brush size is `[`. When I keep it pressed, the brush size reduces quickly with some inertia. I wanted to know how this is implemented. Does it send the keypress event multiple times or does it send the keypress event along with the key down duration, to which the application responds according to the duration?

I suppose this also depends on the OS? I want to know more specifically OSX.

Comment: See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1185792/does-a-usb-keyboard-only-send-signals-or-does-it-also-receive-them-from-the-com#:~:text=the%20host%20sends%20essentially%20%22IN%22%20request%20periodically%2C%20essentially%20polling%20the%20device%20(even%20if%20this%20periodic%20pipe%20is%20called%20%22interrupt%22%20pipe).%20If%20keyboard%20has%20any%20key%20pressed/depressed%2C%20the%20keyboard%20will%20return%20this%20information.%20If%20not%2C%20no%20data%20will%20be%20returned%20to%20the%20device%20driver.).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the behavior on OS X, but this article shows some ways how you can find it out by yourself (without reading the [developer manuals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW1)):

- [Super User: Mouse button and keypress counter for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/399430/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-mac-os-x)

---

On Windows and .NET and "Windows Forms" as the development platform, the behavior would be

> [MSDN: System.Windows.Forms → KeyPressEventArgs Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> ...A [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs when the user presses a key. Two events that are closely related to the [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event are [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) and [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx). The [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event precedes each [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event when the user presses a key, and a [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs when the user releases a key. When the user holds down a key, duplicate [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) events occur each time the character repeats. One [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) event is generated upon release...

See also:

- [MSDN: System.Windows.Input → Keyboard Attached Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard_attachedevents(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Application code typically handles all three events, while the `KeyPress` is actually computed from the down/up signals. Because it mimics the signals received from hardware (see http://wiki.osdev.org/Keyboard for more details) which is OS-neutral I'd expect the OS-APIs to be conceptually very similar